# PowerBI Slicer to Exclude results

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've searched Google results far and wide for a potential solution and I just can't seem to get what I need.  Hoping somebody here will have an idea on what I'm trying to do.

So here's the problem.  I do various financial reporting for my organization and we have thousands of accounts (let's say 5,000), some of which can be considered "outliers". We don't want to exclude them from the results because it's valid data, however we want to give users the ability to view results with, or without, these identified outliers.  So for example, yearly income growth is 8%, but 2.5% excluding Stack Overflow.  Ideally this option (doing xStackOverflow) would be a slicer in PBI so that users can control how they see the results.  Since we have multiple outliers, then I'd like the ability of selecting multiple exclusions.

In Access I was able to create this structure by defining a dimension "business kickout" table that has the name of the exclusion, and then adding the keys of the unique records on a fact table.  Then I created a select query that pulls results where the key is Null on the fact table based on the dimensional business kickout selected.  I'm not an Access expert so this solution isn't elegant, but it's very simple and gets me the results I need.  It also works perfectly for multiple exclusions; i.e. if the key is identified on any exclusion, the record is excluded.

I tried building the same type of logic in PowerBI, but from what I can tell, PBI does not have this "null" option.  Instead it joins the two fact tables, so when I try to "exclude" records the result is ONLY the exclusion, instead of results without the exclusion.

So I could use the same logic and instead of having my fact table store "kickout" keys, I could store "inclusion" keys.  I think I can still get this to work for multiple exclusion options.  However the number of inclusions far outnumbers the number of exclusions, so I'm going from storing say 15 records and identifying as "null" to storing thousands of inclusion records.  Further, since I might have 15 exclusion options, I'll need to store a record for each inclusion for each exclusion option... so my 5,000 account list will grow to nearly 75,000 inclusions pretty quickly.

Has anybody identified an easy way of creating a slicer in PBI to exclude records?

I'll also add that I did explore the thought of including the account name on the report so it can be de-selected, but with thousands of account names to 'include' this solution isn't very user-friendly.

Appreciate any help!!!  Thank you.

EDIT:
I didn't originally notice, but when I create the slicer PBI does add a "(Blank)" option to the slicer that gives the results for the nulls.  So the logic IS there.  It's not exactly the user experience that I wanted (i.e. I have to select the Blank option instead of the xAccount) however I changed the naming of my dimensions to label them as 'include' rather than 'exclude'.  So now my dimension allows me to include exclusions, or exclude exclusions.

Still curious if anybody solved for this issue as it seems that PBI doesn't really have functionality for slicers to exclude results, but I think this method will work for me for now.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the items in the "kickout table" entirely for the report or just optionally?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response; Holidays and such.  I want to do it optionally, if I understand your question correctly.  So users can view the total report and then select a slicer to remove an account, or click again to re-include it.

Comment: Gotcha. It makes a big difference in the approach whether the outliers make it into the report or just get filtered out entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest approach would to maintain an exclusion table like you've created and then simply **Merge** that table with your main dataset (starting from the latter) using a **Left *Anti* Join**.

A left anti join will return a table where there is *not* a match between the column(s) you are joining on. That is, you'll get a table that doesn't contain items from your exclusion table.

---

If this needs to be done dynamically within a report, you can simply set up a slicer with multi-select and select-all functionality, click Select All and then deselect the outliers as desired.

Comment: That may solve the immediate issue, but it's a report that I need to create weekly.  Right now I'm running the dashboard off an Access DB, but I plan on pushing to a SQL table once the dashboard is built and working as intended.  So my goal is to remove the need of manipulating data, and instead just publish 'new' data.

I didn't originally notice the "Blank" slicer that appeared on my slicer options, so it looks like PBI does have a Null join, and I may just need to creatively rename my kickout dimensions to make more sense for users.